# I need to fix bug with react native. what is the problem?

Tags: react-native

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
   

     import React, { PureComponent, useState } from 'react'
        import { StoryContainer } from 'react-native-stories-view'
        import {
            TouchableOpacity,
            Alert,
            StyleSheet,
            View,
            Text,
            SafeAreaView,
            ImageBackground,
            Image,
            Platform,
            StatusBar,
        } from 'react-native'
        
        import { connect } from 'react-redux'
        
        class StoryViewScreen extends PureComponent {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
        
                }
            }
        
            render() {
                const { files } = this.props.route.params;
                const fileUrls = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    fileUrls.push(files[i].uri);
                }
                console.log("files path:", fileUrls);
                return (
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && (
                            <View style={{
                                backgroundColor: 'gray',
                                height: 45,
                            }}>
                                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor={'green'} />
                            </View>
                        )}
                        {Platform.OS === 'android' && (
                            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor={'white'} />
                        )}
        
                        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
                            <StoryContainer
                                visible={true}
                                enableProgress={false}
                                images={fileUrls}
                                duration={5}
                                containerStyle={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    height: '100%',
                                }} />
                            {/* <Text>This is teh realdksfjdsklfj</Text> */}
                        </SafeAreaView>
                    </View>
                );
            }
        };
        
        const style = StyleSheet.create({
        
        });
        
        function mapStateToProps(state) {
            return {
                // currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
            };
        }
        
        function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
            return {
                dispatch
            };
        }
        
        export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StoryViewScreen);
```

Comment: If I add the <StoryContainer>, err occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `useState` in class component, instead use `setState` to set the state.

Comment: Do I need to use setState?

Comment: Yeah, `this.setState`  to set the state, where you are using `useState` in class component

Comment: I didn`t use the useState in this class component.

Comment: For story view, I used react-native-story-views node module and followed sample code as I mentioned above, but err occured

Comment: But, in your code I can see the import of `useState`

Comment: If you had any experience with that module,please tell me how to use it.

Comment: yeah..But I didn`t use it

Comment: Which version of react/ react native you are using ?

Comment: 16.13/0.64 support hook

Comment: don`t worry hook support

Comment: `react-native-stories-view` uses different version : `"react": "16.11.0"`,
    `"react-native": "0.62.1"` this is causing the issue.

Comment: You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.